# passing two generic types as function parameters

Tags: swift

Given as sample function:

```
func sample<Z: Equatable, X: IntegerType>(from: Z.Type, to: X.Type) {
    print("HELLO")
}

sample(String, to: Int)
```

I get the following error `Missing argument for parameter 'to' in call`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this will work

```
sample(String.self, to: Int.self)
```

Comment: Yep, probably XCode auto-suggests that too

Comment: @redent84, no doesn't suggest it